# What is a stage in Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

so I understand that a stage is a set of tasks that work in the same node.

so why do I get two stages when I work in local?

Comment: Stages are created according to (among other rules) independent set of tasks (Transformations and an Action*). Perhaps you've got two separate unrelated flows which can be executed in parallel. Can you share your code? I could be more precise

Comment: it's simple actually                                                                                            `val input = sc.textFile("log.txt")
val splitedLines = input.map(line => line.split(" "))
                        .map(words => (words(0), 1))
                        .reduceByKey{(a,b) => a + b}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stage is a set of parallel tasks - one task per partition.
Number of stages is defined by number of shuffle/wide transformations. [image]

So coming back to your case, if you have shuffle operation then it will result in two stages.